# C++ Structure/Vector Compile Issues

Tags: c++, vector, struct, reference

I'm getting the following compile error that I'm struggling to fix:

error C3867: 'std::vector>::at': function call missing argument list; use '&std::vector>::at' to create a pointer to member

My code is:

```
struct coord_type {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct elements_type {
    vector <coord_type> my_coord;
    coord_type item2;
    coord_type item3;
};
```

And the function with the error is:

```
void position_time(data_type data)
{
    int        i;
    coord_type position;

    for (i = data.elements.my_coord.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        position = data.elements.my_coord.at[i];
    }
}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: .at is a function use .at(i) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`at` is a function, which takes as parameter an index to the data you want. You have 2 options:

- Change `[i]` into `(i)` (because it's a function)
- Access the index using traditional array notation (`data.elements.my_coord[i]`)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to traverse the vector, better to use iterator, here use reverse iterator is better.

```
void position_time(data_type data)
{
    coord_type position;
    for_each(data.elements.my_corrd.rbegin(), data.elements.my_corrd.rend(), [&](coord_type& ct){position = ct;});
}
```